# DayOfWeek get the next DayOfWeek(Monday,Tuesday...Sunday)

Tags: c#, dayofweek

Is there a way to summarize this code into 1-2 lines?

My goal is to return, for example, I have a DayOfWeek which is Monday, I want to get the day after that (Tuesday) or n days after that.

```
         switch (_RESETDAY)
        {
            case DayOfWeek.Monday:
                _STARTDAY = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
                _STARTDAY = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
                _STARTDAY = DayOfWeek.Thursday;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
                _STARTDAY = DayOfWeek.Friday;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Friday:
                _STARTDAY = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                _STARTDAY = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
                break;
            case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                _STARTDAY = DayOfWeek.Monday;
                break;
            default:
                _STARTDAY = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is just an int enumeration, ranging from Sunday (0) to Saturday (6), as per MSDN:

> The DayOfWeek enumeration represents the day of the week in calendars that have seven days per week. The value of the constants in this enumeration ranges from DayOfWeek.Sunday to DayOfWeek.Saturday. If cast to an integer, its value ranges from zero (which indicates DayOfWeek.Sunday) to six (which indicates DayOfWeek.Saturday).

So simple math should do it:

```
DayOfWeek nextDay = (DayOfWeek)(((int)_RESETDAY + 1) % 7);
```

Replace `+ 1` with `+ n` if that's what you need.

Comment: This is the best one.  It accounts for switching from Saturday to Sunday

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

```
(DayOfWeek)((int)(_RESETDAY+1)%7)
```

Answer (score 2):

same result as the addition and modulo stuff answered above, but more readable imho:

```
day = (day == DayOfWeek.Saturday) ? DayOfWeek.Sunday : day + 1;
```

Obvious code intent is always more enjoyable.

Answer (score 0):

```
    static DayOfWeek dayplus (DayOfWeek day)
    {
        if (day == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            return DayOfWeek.Sunday;
        else
            return day + 1;
    }
```

For example

```
Console.WriteLine(dayplus(DayOfWeek.Sunday));
```

Will return monday

Comment: Yes, I noticed the problem with saturday because here week starts on Monday, but I edited

Answer (score 0):

The *general case* solution uses *modulo arithemtics*:

```
  DayOfWeek _RESETDAY = ...;
  int shift = 1; // can be positive or negative

  // + 7) % 7 to support negative shift´s
  DayOfWeek result = (DayOfWeek) ((((int)_RESETDAY + shift) % 7 + 7) % 7);
```

probably, the best implmentation is to *hide* the combersome formula in the *extension method*:

```
 public static class DayOfWeekExtensions {
   public static DayOfWeekShift(this DayOfWeek value, int shift) {
     return (DayOfWeek) ((((int)value + shift) % 7 + 7) % 7);
   }
 }

 ...

 var result = _RESETDAY.Shift(1);
```

and slightly reduced (only works in all cases if negative shift isn't lower than -7) :

```
     return (DayOfWeek)(((int)value + shift + 7) % 7);
```

Comment: @Ian Newson: when `shift < 0` then `%7` can return a *negative value* - so `+7` (and the second `% 7`)  should be added